# "This package should not be accessible on Python 3" when running python3

Tags: python, macos

I was trying to use virtualenv to switch between python versions before learning that I could use both python and python3 on my Mac.

I was able to fix my python 2.7 version so that still works fine however, now when I run python3, I get this error:

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 544, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 530, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 282, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 258, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 601, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 580, in get_config_vars
import _osx_support
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_osx_support.py", line 4, in <module>
import re
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 125, in <module>
import functools
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
from collections import namedtuple
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

I've looked online for this error but most of the conversation was on fixing up the patch and then upgrading virtualenv. However, this still doesn't fix my issue.

```
python3 -V: Python 3.6.0
virtualenv --version: 15.1.0
env | egrep -i 'python|virtualenv': PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
```

Comment: Add the output of `env | egrep -i 'python|virtualenv'` to your question

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added the output

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Your environment contains `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

This doesn't work with Python 3 for obvious reasons. To remove it:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: But I would like to keep both python and python3. Does unsetting affect my python (2.7)?

Comment: If its configuration is correct/sane, it'll have its own `site-packages` in its `sys.path` by default. So if unsetting `PYTHONPATH` breaks your Python 2.7, then something about your Python 2.7 install was already broken.

Comment: For some reason, I have to unset it every time I need to use python3. Is there any way I can make it permanent?

Comment: Find the place where the setting was made permanent in the first place, and undo it. It's not something that's there by default.

Comment: ...if you're having trouble finding that location, try running `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i`, and look for references to `PYTHONPATH` in the output; each line will be prefixed by the source filename and line number where it came from. It's not quite a sure thing that that'll tell you where it's being set (could be something like PAM modules that are invoked before your shell is started), but it's a good place to start.

Comment: I lost this when cleaning up my .zshrc file so have come back here to be rescued again. I can't live without `grcat`.

Answer (score 17):

I solved my problem with below command

```
sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

Comment: FYI for the copy-pasters out there, this will create a virtual environment named `env` running Python 3, which you can then use by activating w/ `source env/bin/activate`. You'll also want to be aware of the `deactivate` and `which python` commands to jump around Python envs. Given the OP wishes to switch between Python 2x and Python 3x, this is the best approach.