# entering ''pip --version'' on ubuntu terminal gives error

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 , when I enter pip --version in the terminal I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diyazen/.local/bin/pip", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 335, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 335, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diyazen/.local/bin/pip", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 335, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

I searched for this error and one solution was provided on one of the threads here to

> unset PYTHONPATH
> ["This package should not be accessible on Python 3" when running python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214414/this-package-should-not-be-accessible-on-python-3-when-running-python3)

After unsetting python path and again running the pip --version I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diyazen/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/diyazen/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Has anyone else also had similar error/ if so how to resolve these kind of error/.
Thank you .

Comment: It looks like your python3 is trying to access pip for your python2. What happens if you try something like `python3 -m pip --version`?

Comment: Hello @MZ Thank you very much for your reply on my issue. Im getting this error https://pastebin.com/vwQDQp9H after adding it

Comment: First check, if pip is installed - `which pip`.

If not then you run - `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.

You need to include pip binary path in .bashrc - `export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin`.

Then you have to run correct version of the python - `python3 -m pip --version`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65869296/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+sys.stderr.write%28f%22ERROR%3A+%7Bexc%7D%22%29

Comment: What's in `~/.local/bin/pip` and why?

Comment: thank you very much for your supportive comments. I was able to resolve the issue thanks to the comments provided here